# How to create custom flags on outlook with javax.mail?

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have created custom flags for gmail using javax.mail api:

```
Flags scannedFlag = new Flags("scanned");
```

So I can search on the folder those messages that doesn't have the scanned flag.

```
FlagTerm fterm = new FlagTerm(scannedFlag, false);      
IMAPFolder folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] messages = folder.search(fterm );
```

And I can assign the custom flag to all messages:

```
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    Message msg = messages[i];
    msg.setFlags(scannedFlag, true);
}
```

This approach works great on gmail, but when I do this with outlook it doesn'work. It give me the following error when I try to asign the scannedFlag on msg :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: A7 BAD Invalid "flag-list": Contains unsupported flag or  closing character missing.;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A7 BAD Invalid "flag-list": Contains unsupported flag or closing character missing.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.setFlags(IMAPMessage.java:921)
    at com.tegik.App.main(App.java:54)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A7 BAD Invalid "flag-list": Contains unsupported flag or closing character missing.
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:353)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.storeFlags(IMAPProtocol.java:1603)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.storeFlags(IMAPProtocol.java:1588)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.setFlags(IMAPMessage.java:917)
```

How could I create custom flags on outlook with a similar approach that I used on gmail?

Answer (score 0):

May be your mailserver does not support custom flags? It can be analyzed through fetching CAPABILITIES. Additionally, what do you mean by 
*This approach works great on gmail, but when I do this with outlook*
I think you connect to different accounts (mailservers) one support custom flags, other not?